# Delphi MS Word automation batch replace old logo with new

Tags: delphi, ms-word

I have about 200 MS Word documents (all .doc format) with our old logo and needed to batch update (delete and replace it with new logo). I first created a macro with vb and got:

```
    ActiveDocument.Shapes("Picture 2").Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Delete
```

Then tried to convert it to automation in Delphi as:

```
    WordApplication.ActiveDocument.Shapes('Picture 2').Select;
```

or

```
    WordApplication.ActiveDocument.Shapes.Select := 'Picture 2';
```

then

```
    WordApplication.Selection.ShapeRange.Delete;
```

However, I get either "Shapes is not a method" or "Select is not supported" errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Round parens `()` in VB can mean either function call parameters, or array index.

In case of `Shapes` ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.shapes)), it is an array indexer, so you have to index the Shapes collection (either `[index]` or via the `Item(index)` method).

`Select()` is a method on the `Shape` *object*, not on the `Shapes` *collection object*.